# Why is Google Sheets unable to apply conditional formatting to multiple cells of different rows and columns?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I realize there are similar questions to mine, but they have not the answer I seek. I want to use the COUNTIF( L5 , 0 ) function to change the color of a diagonal selection of cells. But Google Sheets only colors one cell of my selection. See picture.

[image]

I intend cells D17 and all cells diagonally right and down in a line to become black when cell L5 has a value of 0 entered. For those curious, I'm trying to make a consonant cluster sorter for my conlang projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!

The formula you provided evaluates correctly for cell **D17** because it is the first cell in the specified formatting range.
But for **E18** the condition will change to `=COUNTIF(M6,0)`, for **F19** to `=COUNTIF(N7,0)`, and so on.

To avoid this and use the same formatting condition for all specified cells, use the absolute address of cell **L5** - `=COUNTIF($L$5,0)` in the formula